# Installation of accumulo on CentOS 7 using parcels

Tags: cloudera, centos7, cloudera-manager, accumulo

I am trying to install Accumulo 1.6 using cloudera manager 5.8.1 on Centos 7, I am getting an error: Accumulo Parcel is not available for OS Distribution RHEL7.

Following repo is configured:
https://archive.cloudera.com/accumulo/parcels/latest/

What I understand from the error is on the above link corresponding parcel for el7 i.e centos 7 is unavailable.

How do I install accumulo 1.6 on the CentOS 7? Would there be any compatibility issues with CentOS7?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 7 is not currently supported by the Cloudera packaging for Apache Accumulo for use on CDH. It is planned in an upcoming release.

To find out when CentOS 7 support is added, watch the [Cloudera Community forum on release announcements](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-News-Release/bd-p/RelAnnounce) for a packaging of Apache Accumulo integrated with at least CDH version 5.5, since that was [the CDH version that added support for CentOS 7](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cm_ig_cm_requirements.html#cmig_topic_4_1).

**Edit**: as of 2016-10-11, CentOS 7 packaging is now available for the Cloudera supported distribution, using Apache Accumulo 1.7 integrated with CDH 5.5.0+. Reference the [Cloudera Community forum release announcement for support of Apache Accumulo 1.7 for CDH 5](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-News-Release/ANNOUNCE-Apache-Accumulo-1-7-Support-for-CDH-5/td-p/46142).

Comment: ok Thanks for reference link. Is it possible to manually install and configure accumulo on existing hadoop cluster which was built using parcels?

Comment: Sure, you can follow the build+installation instructions from the Apache Accumulo project and then just point the configuration stuff that needs to know about Hadoop to the correct paths.

You'd have to do this management of Accumulo outside of Cloudera Manager though, which will include relying on HDFS Gateway roles on all the nodes to get proper configs for the CM managed HDFS instance.

Comment: Thank you. I am able toSuccessfully install accumulo.. everything is running smoothly after constant debugging and trouble shooting.